# How to work on own branch and review other PR at same time

Tags: git, github

I am working on My branch, lets call it "My Branch" and I have done lots of changes and also i am not finished with my work. 
My Problem : - Now my peer ask to review his PR lets call it "His Branch" and i want to review that PR. But Whenever i switch to his PR, git ask to stash those changes or commit those changes but My work has too many changes, i can neither stash not commit as there are more changes to be done.

So how can I do both these things at once.

Comment: Why can't you stash? It's exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what `git stash` is *meant* for, so you can stash your own changes in the cupboard (so to speak) while you work on some other item. From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> Use `git stash` when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the `HEAD` commit.

Although I think [this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) expresses it better:

> Often, when you’ve been working on part of your project, things are in a messy state and you want to switch branches for a bit to work on something else. The problem is, you don’t want to do a commit of half-done work just so you can get back to this point later. ***The answer to this issue is the git stash command.***

We don't actually *have* this problem since all our PRs are done using Stash (the product) on the main server but I've had similar issues where I couldn't be bothered stashing stuff. In those cases, I've simply cloned the repo to another local location and worked in there.

In other words, I have a `git-primary` directory and a `git-alternate` one which are totally disassociated from each other, and each can be set to a different branch. If, for some reason, you *really* can't use `git stash`, that may be an option for you.